# Check if dynamically created checkbox is checked or not?

Tags: jquery, checkbox, html-table

I have a table with 16 rows and each row contains checkbox. I need to check if checkbox is checked or not. If check then do something otherwise do something else. I am trying but logic not working:

`BtnGet` is a button in each row. I am firing event on `BtnGet`:

```
$('.btnGet').each(function (i, obj) {
   if ($(obj)
      .closest("tr")
      .children("td:nth-child(3)")
      .find("input[type = checkbox]")
      .checked) 
      {
          console.log("Working");
       }
}
```

Comment: Can't you do `$(<checkbox>).is(':checked')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`checked` is a property of the checkbox DOM element, not the jQuery object. You could use `is(':checked')` instead:

```
$('.btnGet').each(function(i, obj) {
  if ($(obj).closest("tr").find("td:nth-child(3) :checkbox").is(':checked')) {
    console.log("Working");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this:

```js
$('.btnGet tr').each(function (i, obj) {
  if($(this).children().eq(2).find("input[type = checkbox]").is(":checked")){
    console.log('checked');
  }else{
     console.log('not checked');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="btnGet" style="width:500px;height:500px;border:1px solid;">
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td><input type="checkbox" checked></td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td><input type="checkbox" ></td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td><input type="checkbox" checked></td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td><input type="checkbox" checked></td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td><input type="checkbox" ></td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td><input type="checkbox" ></td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td><input type="checkbox" checked></td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td><input type="checkbox" checked></td></tr>
</table>
```